# Can I take a mapping from one contract, and access it with an interface from anther contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mapping, interfaces

Lets say I have a mapping in contract A, which is already deployed.. Can I use an interface in contract B to access the mapping (and the values it links)? If not, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Map is a variable, same way as a string or an address. Not sure if you can access any of those without a specific function that returns the variable. But I saw some tricks how to get it, even for private variables: https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-quick-guide-to-hack-private-variables-in-solidity-b45d5acb89c0  But that is hacking.

Comment: From where are you calling? Another contract on-chain or from an off-chain app.

Comment: Another contract on-chain

Answer (score 1):

From another contract you can only access public variables.

For example given these contracts, B can access foo when it is declared public. B cannot access them if they were private or internal.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract A {
    mapping (address => uint256) public foo;

    function bar(address k, uint256 v) public {
        foo[k] = v;
    }
}


contract B {
    A public a;

    constructor(A _a) {
        a = _a;
    }
    function read(address k) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 x = a.foo(k);
        return x + 1234;
    }
}
```